# Data is not inserted in Many to Many mapping?

Tags: hibernate-mapping

i have three DB tables

1. route(route_id)
2. stop(stop_id)
3. route_stop(route_id,stop_id)---mapping table

Route.hbm.xml

```
<set name="stops" table="route_stop" cascade="all"><key column="route_id" /><many-to-many column="stop_id" class="com.trackingsystem.model.Stop" /></set>
```

Stop.hbm.xml

```
<set name="routes" table="route_stop" cascade="all"><key column="stop_id" /><many-to-many column="route_id" class="com.trackingsystem.model.Route" />
```

but data is not inserted in the DB,

it is showing these select queries

```
    

Hibernate: 
    /* get current state com.trackingsystem.model.Stop */ select
        stop_.stop_id,
        stop_.stop_name as stop2_106_,
        stop_.lattitude as lattitude106_,
        stop_.langitude as langitude106_ 
    from
        trackingsystem.stop stop_ 
    where
        stop_.stop_id=?


Hibernate: 
    /* get current state com.trackingsystem.model.Stop */ select
        stop_.stop_id,
        stop_.stop_name as stop2_106_,
        stop_.lattitude as lattitude106_,
        stop_.langitude as langitude106_ 
    from
        trackingsystem.stop stop_ 
    where
        stop_.stop_id=?
```

where is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is i didn't flush the session. After that every thing is ok.
thanks.